# How to inline two image Divs inside a Div?

Tags: html, css, inline

I am struggling to place both divs inline by each other, any suggestions people? Everything I am trying within CSS is not working like Float(img-1): Left and Float (img-2): Right, display: inline-block etc.

```
<div class="multimedia-img"> 
  <div class="img-1">  
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
    <img src="images/youtube.png" style="width: 200px; height: 140px;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="img-2">
    <a href="https://www.ted.com/talks">
    <img src="images/ted.png" style="width: 200px; height: 160px;">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Added my CSS below to show you what I have done so far...

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #505050;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.container{

    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color: #1B0C0C;
    height: 114px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    white-space: pre-line;
}

.hobbies{
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.img-hobby {
    width: 50%;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 47px;
    margin-right: -295px;
}

.text-hobby {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-left: 20%;

}

.friends{
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.img-friends{
    width: 50%;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
}

.text-friends{
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-left: 20%;

}


.multimedia-img{

    display: inline-block;
}

.img-1{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.img-2{
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}


img{
    padding-top: 17px;
    border-radius: 125px;
}

p{
    font-weight: bold;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;


}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


li a:hover {
    background-color: #61C8ED;
}

li a:hover:not(.header) {
    background-color: #000000;
}

.header{
    background-color: #61C8ED;
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could post your CSS markup. Thank you.

Comment: I have posted my CSS, hopefully this is more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

try adding display: inline-block

```
 .multimedia-img{
   ....
   display: inline-block;
   ....
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Float**

You float both divs and clear the parent element, e.g. with `overflow:hidden;`

```
.multimedia-img {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-1, .img-2 {
  float: left;
}
```

**Flexbox**

Set the parent to `display: flex;`

```
.multimedia-img {
   display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here i think you want to do this

https://jsfiddle.net/yec8p3vt/

**html**

```
<div class="multimedia-img"> 
  <div class="img">  
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
    <img src="images/youtube.png" style="width: 200px; height: 140px;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <a href="https://www.ted.com/talks">
    <img src="images/ted.png" style="width: 200px; height: 160px;">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do both:

```css
.multimedia-img {
  display: inline;
}
.img-1,
.img-2 {
  display: inherit;
}
```

Or:

```css
.img-1,
.img-2 {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i would recommend Flexbox. So easy :)

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox